# How to show array values into select control using foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, html-select

I've an array in PHP titled `$volume_unit_list` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [unit] => Microsecond
            [created_at] => 1397479783
            [updated_at] => 1397479783
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [unit] => oz
            [created_at] => 1397548900
            [updated_at] => 1397672502
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [unit] => ml
            [created_at] => 1397641838
            [updated_at] => 1397672480
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [unit] => L
            [created_at] => 1397672517
            [updated_at] => 1397672517
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [unit] => gms
            [created_at] => 1398196412
            [updated_at] => 1398196412
        )

)
```

I want to add all the elements from above array to the HTML select control using `foreach($volume_unit_list as $key=>$value)` but I'm not able to do that. In the proposed select control by default selected option text should be Select Unit whose value should be "". And for all other array elements the option text should be `[unit]` key's value from above array and option value should be concernen `[id]` key's value from above array. Can someone please help me in this regard, please. The unsuccessful code I tried is as follows:

```
<?php
    $rebate_no = $_POST['rebate_no'];

  echo "<tr id='reb$rebate_no'>
  <td><div class='btn-group'><select id='units_$rebate_no' name='units[$rebate_no]' class='form-control'><option value='' selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>foreach($volume_unit_list as $key=>$value){<option value='$value[id]'>$value[unit]</option>}</select></div></td>
  </tr>";
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you're pretty new to PHP, despite your username.

Comment: @AmalMurali:The fact is I get very confuse with HTML and foreach loop code combination. I've added my corrected code at the end of my question but still the array elements are not getting displayed into select control. Can you please look into that? It will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this ,   you have a lot  of syntax error

```
echo "<select id='unit' name='units[]' class='form-control'>";
foreach($volume_unit_list as $key=>$value) {
    echo "<option value='{$key['id']}'>${key['unit']}</option>";

}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: :Thanks for your help. As per your suggestion, I've corrected and added my actual code at the end of my question. But still it's not printing the array elements into select control. Can you look into this please?

Comment: @DarkSide:I tried as you said but still it's not displaying array elements into select control. Do you have any other way?

Comment: @PHPLover This is correct way to do this. One more bug in this answer is that last line should be `</select>` not `<select>`

Comment: @DarkSide:You can see the corrected code I've appended to the question where all the small errors have been removed. But not getting why the array elements are not getting print.

Comment: OK I'll create complete answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

you should use string concatenation(but using templates is the best)

```
<?php
    $str="<select id='unit' name='units[]' class='form-control'><option value=''>Select Unit</option>";

    foreach($volume_unit_list as $key=>$value) {
       $str .= "<option value='$key[id]'>$key[unit]</option>";
    }

    $str .="</select>";


?>
```

Comment: :Thanks for your help. As per your suggestion, I've corrected and added my actual code at the end of my question. But still it's not printing the array elements into select control. Can you look into this please?

Comment: Oh common, copying another answer is evil :) At least replace correct bugs before you copy (replace $key with $value in <option> line).

Comment: @DarkSide:I've updated my question. Now you can see the almost rightly written code but still not workable. Not understanding why the array elements are not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the array, you need to access indexes from second dimension of array, which would be:

```
echo "<select id='unit' name='units' class='form-control'>";
echo "<option value=\"\">Select value</option>";
foreach ($volume_unit_list as $key => $value) {
echo "<option value=\"".$value['id']."\">".$value['unit']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

In the foreach section, $value is the internal array holding your values with indexes 'id', 'unit', e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

Here is corrected source code. Not sure why you need this table row and POST and rebate_no, but I guess you know why :)

```
$volume_unit_list = array( /* ... */);
$rebate_no = $_POST['rebate_no'];

// prepare options
$s = '';
foreach($volume_unit_list as $v) {
    $s .= "<option value='{$v['id']}'>{$v['unit']}</option>";
}

// echo out
echo "
<tr id='reb$rebate_no'><td><div class='btn-group'>
    <select id='units_$rebate_no' name='units[$rebate_no]' class='form-control'>
        <option value='' selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
        $s
    </select>
</div></td></tr>";
```